# Blackberry Pearl CSS forcing all elements inline

Tags: css, mobile, browser

I am trying to customise a site's CSS using a Blackberry Pearl (8120) but it seems that the phone forces elements to display inline.

I can't force any of the following rules: `display: block;`
`display: none;` and `text-indent: -99999px;`

The problem is I have no real control over the HTML. I have `<h1>`'s displaying as a block level element and a background image, with text inside, but no span or other element. It seems I  have no real way of getting rid of the contained text.

Is there any way to force the device to listen to my CSS instead of using the phone's browser overrides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with blackberries of that era is you were lucky if it handled your HTML. CSS was a no go zone. Especially with the perl which had a lot of "phonizing" features. Anyhow, the biggest variable is what version of BBOS and BB browser you are running there as that would give a better target to aim at. Or just do the rational thing and stop supporting ancient mobile devices they don't even sell anymore.

Comment: Ok I think I am going to press with the rational thing. Thanks for the answer.